# Multiplatform way to send and receive data through serial port in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, arduino, serial-port, multiplatform

I want to send and receive data from my Arduino in my Java application. Another feature I need is list of open serial ports. I just want to ask if there is some elegant way to do it in Java 8. I want to send receive primitive data types and Strings. I need to make this work on MacOS, Linux and Windows. How could I possibly achive it ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I use [JSSC](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector) for Java projects for serial comunications with Arduino.

Its works very well and run in Windows and macOS (linux I not tried yet)